# SQL Query custom result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Query like

```
Select CONCAT('"',CONVERT(date,getdate()),'"')
```

It will produce a result like this:

> "2016-07-15"

but I want the result to be in single quotes, not double quotes like this:

> '2016-07-15'

I tried using

```
Select CONCAT(''',CONVERT(date,getdate()),''')
```

But it produces an error.

How can I accomplish the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('''',CONVERT(date,getdate()),'''')
```

In SQL Server you have to double single quotes up in order to escape them.